# How to use innertHTML, in this following situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

We were given an assignment to basically make a Madlib by having the user enter words into textfields and then replacing words in a hidden paragraph existing in the html page. We have to use JavaScript and CSS.

the paragraph in the html page:

```
<span id="story" display="hidden">
Rain was still lashing the windows, which were now <span id="adjs1">__adjective__</span>, but inside all looked bright and cheerful. The firelight glowed over 
the countless <span id="adjs2">___adjective___</span> <span id="plnouns">___plural_noun___</span> where people sat <span id="verbs1">___verb_with_ing___</span>
, talking, doing homework or, in the case of Fred and George Weasley, trying to find out what would happen if you fed a <span id="foods">___food___</span> to a 
<span id="monsters1">___monster___</span>. Fred had "rescued" the <span id="adjs3">___adjective___</span>, fire-dwelling <span id="monsters2">___monster___</
span> from a Care of Magical Creatures class and it was now<span id="verbs2">___verb_with_ing___</span> gently on a table surrounded by a knot of curious peopl. 
</span>
```

Everything was going fine till I keep missing on getting the results I want.

```
 function generateMadlib(){
    // Display the story. The story is initially hidden.
    document.getElementById("story").style.display = "inline";
    // Get the words from the textboxes.
    var formElements = $("#madlibForm :text");

    // Find the word locations on the hidden paragraph.
    var storyWords = $("#story span");

    // Replace word loc values with with formElement values
    for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
    {
      storyWords.eq(i).innerHTML = formElements.eq(i).val();
    }
}
```

This line

```
storyWords.eq(i).innerHTML = formElements.eq(i).val();
```

doesn't change the values inside the spans within the paragraph. (the code returns the proper input on the textfields)

I also tried using the browser console and manually changing document.getElementById("adjs1").innerHTML = "test"; it will return "test" but the value doesn't actually change. Can anyone clarify what .innerHTML actually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.eq(i)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns a jQuery object so it don't have the innerHTML property, so you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the html content

```
storyWords.eq(i).html(formElements.eq(i).val())
```

or you can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) which will return a dom element reference

```
storyWords.get(i).innerHTML = formElements.eq(i).val();
```

---

But you can simplify the overall implementation like

```
function generateMadlib() {
    // Display the story. The story is initially hidden.
    $("#story").css('display', "inline");
    // Get the words from the textboxes.
    var formElements = $("#madlibForm :text");

    $("#story span").html(function (idx) {
        return formElements.eq(idx).val();
    })
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much. So i was just using the wrong format the entire time? I have to check what .get() does.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's regarding html properties in both cases, thanks again.